# How to run xamarin forms designer?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

How to run xamarin forms designer?

After startup, an error pops up:

> The previewer requires a 64-bit version of Oracle Java JDK 8 (1.8) or
>   higher. Please install it and then set the Java JDK location in the
>   Xamarin Studio or Visual Studio preferences.

But I'm using version 1.8.

How to fix?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You aren't using the 64-bit install of JDK 1.8, you're using the 32-bit.

Install the 64-bit version and change that path you highlighted from:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_101`

to

`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101`